# Guidance needed in Writing Specifications

Tags: specifications

I was asked (at a place i just began working) to create simple specs for some new functionality that is going to be added to an existing Registration system. I need a little help since i've never done this before.
Here are two diagrams that show the current workflow and the new workflow.

- Current Workflow: http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/102/currentworkflow.png
- New Workflow http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/6748/newworkflow.png

I know they might be a bit vague but here's what's basically happening.
We are adding a new import form to an existing windows application.
We are modifying an existing form by adding a search button which will search
search and populate data read by an ocr.

I'm a new developer and i'm pretty bad at writing documents in general, but i would like to improve on this. Maybe some examples on how to go about writing something like this would be helpful. I've googled for some examples, but most of the ones i've found are on creating a brand new system. I need something that shows how to write one for modifying an exisiting system.

**Here's my attempt at a specification. Maybe someone can critique it. At least then i will know what i need to improve. http://cid-ddb3f6a92ec2b97e.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/Specs.docx**

Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that. I modified the question to be a little more clear.

Comment: @zSysop - I've updated my answer with some comments on the spec you posted. It's a bit of a brain dump on my part, but hopefully it will be somewhat useful. Feel free to ignore any parts you disagree with, just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I love writing specs (I'm a rare one in my company).

Diagrams are a good way to go, but for the more literally minded I start with a full specification template that has a ton of headings in it. For a new system, you'd generally have something to say for everyone. In your case you've specifically mentioned it's an existing app you're modifying, but the point is not to fill out all of the headings - the point is to *think about them*, and then delete them after due consideration. For example:

- Business Requirements (short synopsis of the need, as explained to the business, non-technical users)
- Use Cases (usually for bigger specs only)
- Functional Requirements

  - Overview
  - Flowcharts etc.
  - Configuration
  - Error Reporting
  - Testing
  - Documentation
  - Training
  - Assumptions and Additional Constraints
  - Third-party Software Requirements
  - Internationalization
  - Expandability (e.g. for bits that might need to plug-in to others etc)
  - Customization
  - Questions (for questions that still need to be answered by someone to finish the spec)

Also if it's really technical then you might need an introduction sections for:
 - Target Audience
 - Terminology
 - Examples

All of these is generally overkill for all but the largest of designs. But even for a modification, I'd go through every item and consider whether I need to write anything or not. I think this is where a lot of the value of writing a spec comes from - the process of creation. In other words, trying to be thorough and not miss too much. All the benefits that come afterwards - like being able to do estimates, being able to explain the functionality to others etc - are nice side-effects. As long as it doesn't end up completely garbled, and suits your company okay, I think that's more important than the specific appearance, format or contents of the spec.

**EDIT: Comments on [your specification](http://cid-ddb3f6a92ec2b97e.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/Specs.docx)**

I think you've done a reasonable job here. Most developers should be able to take the spec and produce something sensible, and most business analysts should be able to look at the spec and work out what it does and how it works. In my comments below, keep in mind that there's always a trade-off between how detailed you want the spec and how much time you have. I tend to believe the more detailed the spec the more time everyone saves, but that's not the case for everyone.

- If you want this to be clearly understood by a business user (e.g. the customer), then the Objective section could maybe contain a sentence or two describing the problem it solves. In other words not *what* it will achieve, but *why*.
- It's worth explicitly naming the intermediate staging table here. At the very least it means if someone comes back to the spec a year from now, they know exactly where to look in the database.
- Minor point: in my experience screenshots that contain unrealistic data are harder to understand. Instead of showing "My Sample Form", "Name", "Address" etc, it'd perhaps be easier to understand with some sensible data. Can still be fake to protect the customer's data, like "123 Fake St" etc. Not a huge deal though.
- It's not clear what will happen when something goes wrong. Are there to be any checks that the data in the staging table is in a valid format? If not, is the user given an error message, or otherwise logged somewhere? One error per row of invalid data, or one for the whole batch? The form consists of a single button - something I think we can agree isn't the world's greatest UI, but I understand sometimes these things happen - perhaps it could be enhanced with a logging window to show the results of the import. The answers might be straightforward, but the developer needs to know what they are.

  - Perhaps not an issue depending on how much data there is, but if there was a lot and it will take a while, it might be worth having a progress bar. Or, mention if the data will be imported in stages.
- Would it be worth mentioning the definition of the permanent table to which data is moved? Are all fields moved from the staging table to the permanent table, or only some? If only some, can you show what maps to what? If the permanent table has different data lengths - for example if `Address Street` is a Varchar(30) - what would happen if the data won't fit? Again, perhaps simple answers, but ones that would be very usefully answered here.
- Perhaps worth mentioning if the data will be imported in a single transaction or not - if the data import fails partway through, if everything rolled back, or is half the imported data left imported?
- If another developer will be doing this work, I think they're *far* more likely to get the work right if you mocked-up / draw the screens for them. Even if it's just a form with one button, and even though I can take a good guess at what your search pop-up form will look like, I would make no mistakes if I knew exactly what it's supposed to look like. Tools like [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) (and see examples [here](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/examples#exportdialog)) are wonderful for quick mocks, though the default "comic sans" look may not ride well with managers. I'd rather have a dirty mockup than none at all though. (Note: the free version of Balsamiq doesn't let you save images, but you can achieve the same with the export/import functionality. Also you can't save to an image file like PNG etc, but you can use a screen-capture program to take a picture of what you draw.)
- Minor point: I try to avoid personal pronouns like "I", "we", "our", just to make it a little more professional and better for customers to read if necessary. I only noticed one "our", so you've mostly got it right in terms of tone here.
- Minor point: are varchars enough or will there be non-standard characters in there that require unicode (i.e. nvarchar)?
- It's less clear to me what's happening in the Voter Add/Update Form, but I don't have knowledge of your application - maybe everyone involved will say "oh right, I get it". For example I don't understand the relevance of "ImpRecord001" and "ImpRecord002" - would it be worth mentioning in the design what these batch codes actually mean in the real world?
- Is the "Search Data" button the same as the "Search OCR" button?

Comment: I believe you're probably a rare one in *any* company, upvoted for the good advice =)

Comment: Thanks alot gavin.
I wasn't sure at all if what i had was anywhere in the right direction. You've helped immensely!

Comment: No worries, like anything you'll get better at them over time too. You learn the most about what you've missed and what you've got right when a) a non-technical business analyst tries to read it or b) if you're not developing it yourself, you see how much the developer gets right/wrong in the implementation. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

For any document: first consider why you are writing it - who will read it, what do they need to know? How much detail is appropriate? Another couple of general ideas

If may be useful to then think about the sources of  information that go into what you are writing. One result of that might be that you make sure that what you write can be verified. If for example an information source is a person, especially for IT docs it might be a non-IT person telling you stuff, then you may be quite careful about how your present some information so that the "source" can also understand what you are saying.

Also consider carefully what comes after the current document. For example might a test plan be written on the basis of what you write? This might lead you to present information in tables that quite naturally get expanded to test cases.

So to your specific question. What do you mean by "spec"? The workflow you give isn't enough for a user to look at and agree "Yes please, that's what I want". It's not enough for someone to write some code.  I'm thinking you might need several documents.

1). Some kind of requirements doc. One format you might use is a storyboard. This focuses on what the user can see and do. Exactly what data is shown on each screen. If there are computations underlying what's displayed you may need to have appendices describing these. This doc is read by both users and developers. Powerpoint or Word could be used.

2). From that you might derive some explicit data models. Item-by-item, field-by-field. data types, sizes, validation etc.  I might use  date modelling tool, or UML or just a spreadsheet. Primary audience is developer, but ideally a user (or a business anlyst intermediary) could verify the details. [If you don't have a business analyst, you probably **are** the business analyst :-) ]

3). More technical, a spec for the developers referring to items 1&2. A decomposition of the implemntation. Names of modules, packages, classes or whatever you are using. Defintions of transformations, algorithms and calculations. A more technical doc. I would use UML, but any precise form of capture would do. This is where we might really drill down into what some of the detailed boxes in your workflow mean.

As has been observed, in general we also need to make sure the developer udnerstands the non-functional requirements, such as security and data volumes. In your situation this may be be implcitly understood, so possibly you may not need it now ... in some other life you may, so it might be a good idea to at least have a one liner in place to remind you for the future.

Comment: Thanks djna. Do you have any full blown examples of going through the creation process for steps 1-4? This would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I can't share docs that I produce or use on customer engagements I'm afraid. As an IBM-er I would naturally draw on material from my  Rational colleagues, relating to RUP, for example: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/03July/1000/1251/1251_bestpractices_TP026B.pdf - I would expect that similar example material could be found for other well defined processes with a tad of Googling.

Answer (score 1):

Those are an excellent start for a spec.

I would add to them by creating mock screen shots of what you want the windows application to look like.

On top of that you can add the details of each data field, and what the allowed values are.

Include details of any exceptions you can think of, and how you want errors reported.

You might also want to consider what sort of reporting, and security/auditing you need, as these will need to be included in the design.

Finally, it's worthwhile to sit down with the developer and talk them through the process, going through each step, as i'm sure further details will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the steps down at the bottom are a bit wordy. Try splitting them up and make sure the word IF never appears. IFs should be designated by using a diamond and splitting out the flow paths based on the conditional.